# String to Object but not Object to String?

Tags: java

I can't really understand why this line of code doesn't compile:

```
String str = new Object();
```

while the following does:

```
Object o = new String("Hello");
```

To my understand, String, like every other class, extends Object. So why doesn't the first line compile?

Comment: The type of object on the right must be or extend the type on the left. Object is not a String nor does it extend String.

Comment: You need to find a basic text on object-oriented programming and study it.  (Seriously.  You're not going to understand the concepts from 100-word answers on SO.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Because `String` is an `Object`, but `Object` is not a `String`, just like every **orange** is a **fruit**, but not every **fruit** is an **orange**.

`String` is a class that extends `Object`, so you can simply write:

```
Object obj = "string";
```

But `Object` does not extend `String`, so:

```
String str = new Object();
```

won't compile.

Though, if you have an `Object`, and it is a `String`, you can do something that is called *type casting* or simply *casting*:

```
String str = (String) myObject;
```

But it might throw a `ClassCastException` if `myObject` is not originally type of `String`

Here, you can find more information on *Object Casting* in Java: http://www.javabeginner.com/learn-java/java-object-typecasting

Comment: So the statement String str = new Object(); roughly translates to: str is an Object of type String? I'm trying to get an intuitive understanding of how to read that line of code.

Comment: If your object is a string, then you can do String str = (String) object;
Known as "Casting"

Answer (score 4):

For this sort of thing it is useful to distinguish between the type of a variable, established in its declaration, and the class of an object, established when the object is created.

A variable is allowed to be `null`, or to point to any object whose class matches its type, or is a direct or indirect subclass of that class. Because `String` is a subclass of `Object`, a variable of type `Object` can point to an object of class `String`.

In your example, the compiler knows that a `String` expression must be `null` or point to a `String` object, so `Object o = new String("Hello");` is known at compile time to be correct.

On the other hand, an expression or variable of type `Object` may reference a String, but it may reference something entirely different. The compiler requires an explicit cast to say the conversion is OK.

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object stringObject = "xyzzy";
    Object integerObject = new Integer(3);
    String test1 = (String)stringObject;
    System.out.println(test1);
    String test2 = (String) integerObject;
    System.out.println(test2);
  }
}
```

This program compiles because I've told the compiler the conversions are OK with my casts. It runs through the first `println` call, because `stringObject` really does point to a `String`. It fails with a `ClassCastException` on the line `String test2 = (String) integerObject;`. As far as the compiler knows, `integerObject` might point to a `String`, so it accepted my cast. At run time, the JVM finds it really points to an `Integer` and throws the exception.

The use of type `Object` for integerObject is significant. That makes `String test2 = (String) integerObject;` conversion of a type Object expression to type String, a conversion that might succeed, depending on what `integerObject` actually references. If `integerObject` had declared type `Integer` the compiler would have rejected the program. There is no object that can be referenced by both `Integer` and `String` expressions.